# Scraping data from a site where URL doesn't change on clicking 'Show More'

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, lazy-loading, webdriverwait

I'm trying to scrape all the article links from a site and have I been successful in doing so.

The site page has a `Show more` button for loading more articles.

I'm using Selenium to click on this button which also works.

The problem is that clicking on `Show more` doesn't change the URL of the page, therefore I'm being able to scrape only the initial links displayed by default.

Here is the code snip:

```
def startWebDriver():
    global driver
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = '/home/Downloads/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver',options=options)

startWebDriver()
count = 0 
s = set()

driver.get('https://www.nytimes.com/search? endDate=20181231&query=trump&sort=best&startDate=20180101')
time.sleep(4)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="site-content"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/button')

while(count < 10):
    element.click()
    time.sleep(4)
    count=count+1

url = driver.current_url
```

I expect to get all article links displayed on the page after clicking on `Show More` 10 times

Comment: have you used `set` on the data shown in the first iteration to the second and third?

Comment: yes..I'm using set to collect all the article links

Comment: The site doesn't and won't change the url you're on, because it fetches the new data to display by ajax. When you click "Show More", the frontend JS sends a request to the server to get more data, and when that's fulfilled, the response is added to the HTML of the currently loaded page; e.g. a trivial dynamic page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To scrape all the article links i.e the `href` attributes from the [URL](https://www.nytimes.com/search?%20endDate=20181231&query=trump&sort=best&startDate=20180101) clicking on the link with text as **SHOW MORE** you can use the following solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.nytimes.com/search?%20endDate=20181231&query=trump&sort=best&startDate=20180101")
myLength = len(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//main[@id='site-content']//figure[@class='css-rninck toneNews']//following::a[1]"))))

while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Show More']"))).click()
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver: len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//main[@id='site-content']//figure[@class='css-rninck toneNews']//following::a[1]")) > myLength)
        titles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//main[@id='site-content']//figure[@class='css-rninck toneNews']//following::a[1]")
        myLength = len(titles)
    except TimeoutException:
        break

for title in titles:
    print(title.get_attribute("href"))
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a mimic of a POST request using API info as I see in network tab. I have stripped back to headers that seems to be required.

```
import requests
url = 'https://samizdat-graphql.nytimes.com/graphql/v2'
headers = {
         'nyt-app-type': 'project-vi',
         'nyt-app-version': '0.0.3',
         'nyt-token': 'MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAlYOpRoYg5X01qAqNyBDM32EI/E77nkFzd2rrVjhdi/VAZfBIrPayyYykIIN+d5GMImm3wg6CmTTkBo7ixmwd7Xv24QSDpjuX0gQ1eqxOEWZ0FHWZWkh4jfLcwqkgKmfHJuvOctEiE/Wic5Qrle323SMDKF8sAqClv8VKA8hyrXHbPDAlAaxq3EPOGjJqpHEdWNVg2S0pN62NSmSudT/ap/BqZf7FqsI2cUxv2mUKzmyy+rYwbhd8TRgj1kFprNOaldrluO4dXjubJIY4qEyJY5Dc/F03sGED4AiGBPVYtPh8zscG64yJJ9Njs1ReyUCSX4jYmxoZOnO+6GfXE0s2xQIDAQAB'
}

data = '''
{"operationName":"SearchRootQuery","variables":{"first":10,"sort":"best","beginDate":"20180101","text":"trump","cursor":"YXJyYXljb25uZWN0aW9uOjk="},"extensions":{"persistedQuery":{"version":1,"sha256Hash":"d2895d5a5d686528b9b548f018d7d0c64351ad644fa838384d94c35c585db813"}}}
'''
with requests.Session() as r:
    re = r.post(url, headers = headers, data = data)
    print(re.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your target resource give us a nice API for their articles.

It will be much easier to use it instead of selenium.

You can open that page in Chrome. Then open Dev Tools -> Network. Click on "Show more" and you can see API request named v2 (looks like it is GraphQL gateway).

Something like

```
{
    "operationName":"SearchRootQuery",
    "variables":{
        "first":10,
        "sort":"best",
        "beginDate":"20180101",
        "endDate":"20181231",
        "text":"trump" ...
}}
```

You can mimic that request but ask as many "first" articles as you want.

**EDIT**:

You can right-click in DevTools and select "copy as cURL". Then paste it to your terminal. So you can see how it works.

After that you can use library like [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) to do it from your code.

Comment: Thanks..how do I mimic that request ?